# C structure type variable declaration

Tags: arrays, c, structure

I have written a code for a ticket reservation halfway and I'm doubtful about the way i have used structures and arrays in my code. This code is not formatted properly because I am trying to see if this method of declaring "Bill" type variable will work or is this wrong?
the code gets compiled and runs successfully but I am doubtful whether my method is correct. Can anyone help? I just want to know whether the way I have declared structure type variables and used it is correct?Especially the last printf statement where I calculate the Amount.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SIZE 3


typedef struct
{
        int billno;
        char name[20];
        char cat[20];
        int type;
        int range[3];
        int tickets;
        int class[3];
        float price;        
}Bill;
int main()

{
        Bill array[3];
        Bill d;
        int input; 
        
        array[0].billno=6434;
        strcpy(array[0].name,"Nimal");
        strcpy(array[0].cat,"General");
        array[0].type=1;
        array[0].range[0]= 250;
        array[0].range[1]= 0;
        array[0].range[2]= 0;
        array[0].price = 200;
        
        array[1].billno=6065;
        strcpy(array[1].name,"Kamal");
        strcpy(array[1].cat,"Industrial");
        array[1].type=2;
        array[1].range[0]=622;
        array[1].range[1]=1999;
        array[1].range[2]=102;
        array[1].price =125.60;
        
        array[2].billno=7067;
        strcpy(array[2].name,"Gayani");
        strcpy(array[2].cat,"General");
        array[2].type=2;
        array[2].range[0]=220;
        array[2].range[1]=350;
        array[2].range[2]=10;
        array[2].price = 86.90; 
        printf("****Main Menu****");
   printf("1.Reserve a ticket:");
   scanf("%d",&input);
   if(input == 1)
    {
     printf("Enter your name: ");
     scanf("%s", d.name);
     printf("Enter the number of tickets you want");
     scanf("%d",&d.tickets);
     printf("Enter the number of tickets from first class");
     scanf("%d",&d.class[0]);
     printf("Enter the number of tcikets from second class");
     scanf("%d",&d.class[1]);
     printf("Enter the number of tickets from third class");
     scanf("%d",&d.class[2]);
    }


   printf("\nReserve a ticket");
   printf("\nName : %s",d.name);
   printf("\nTickets from first class : %d",d.class[0]);
   printf("Tickets from second class : %d\n",d.class[1]);
   printf("Tickets from third class : %d\n",d.class[2]);
   printf("\nConfirm the order? press Y if yes : ");
   
    printf("Amount = %.2f ",d.class[0]*array[0].price+d.class[1]*array[1].price+d.class[2]*array[2].price);
         


         
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The way you did it instanciates 3 Bill structures in an array, on the stack, if it is your goal, then it's correct. However, you should consider to write a function to initialize a Bill structure, or initialize them during the declaration.

Comment: This is very code for your question. Please reduce it to a [mre]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more of a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question, than a SO question. The OP clearly states the code compiles and runs correctly and is asking for advice on code style.

Comment: I would suggest that `array` is not a very good name - when it looks like things in array are effectively "templates" of the costs of different types of tickets.